# SPRING --- How to submit an array of object to controller

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, angularjs

As title,

i using angularjs to submit

my spring controller:

```
@RequestParam(value = "hashtag[]") hashtag[] o
```

above are work for array parameter but not an array object

my js script:

```
$http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: url,
         data: $.param({
                hashtag : [{label:"success",value:"ok"},{label:"success",value:"ok"},{label:"success",value:"ok"}],
               }),
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  });
```

i observe from chrome, the form data is

```
    hashtag[0][label]:success
    hashtag[0][value]:10

    hashtag[1][label]:success
    hashtag[2][value]:10

    hashtag[3][label]:success   
    hashtag[3][value]:10
```

But the Spring show me

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required hashtag[] parameter 'id[]' is not present
```

Previously i was able to receive an array of parameters, but not an object. so can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `@ModelAttribute`

Create a new Java class HashtagList like given below

```
public class HashTagList {

    private List<HashTag> hashTag;

    public List<HashTag> getHashTag() {
        return hashTag;
    }

    public void setHashTag(List<HashTag> hashTag) {
        this.hashTag = hashTag;
    }
}
```

and in your controller method

```
@ModelAttribute("hashtag") HashTagList hashTagList
```

Is the java class name hashtag or HashTag ?

Comment: can more specific? @RequestBody with an error(org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported),
if i didnt specific ('Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') there will be no form data.

Comment: :), not. its by a form data.

Comment: Requestbody annotation handles xml and json data if you want to submit form data you have to use @ModelAttribute

Comment: tried, but for 1 object only. For multiple object in array(i have edited the sample code, to make it more easy understand), i have no way to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Try @RequestParam(value = "hashtag") hashtag[] o

Given that you have a class named hashtag havinf label and value attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a POST request you can use `@RequestBody` annotation and create a DTO class to map the data you are sending or maybe even use your domain object.
For example, why not create reusable POJO class that can hold key->value pairs like:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"label", "value"})
public final class Pair<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V>, Serializable {
   private final K key;
   private final V value;

   @JsonCreator
   public Pair(@JsonProperty("label")K key, @JsonProperty("value")V value) {
       this.key = key;
       this.value = value;
   }
   // ... rest of the implementation
}
```

Note: I have assumed here you are using Jackson mapper, hence the JSON annotations.
Next step is to get the class that will hold the data structure you are sending from  your client:

```
public class HashTags implements Serializable {
    List<Pair<String, String>> hashtag = new ArrayList<>();
   // ... rest of the implementation
}
```

Then in your controller you will have to do something like:

```
@RequestBody HashTags entity
```